# Transfer Current Website Comments to the Facebook Comment Social Plugin

Tags: comments, facebook-social-plugins, facebook-comments

My team would like to replace our current custom commenting system with the [Facebook Comment Social Plugin](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/plugins/comments/).  We don't want to lose any of our existing comments so my question is:

Is it possible to export the comments from our current system and import them into Facebook's Comment Plugin using the Facebook Graph API?